# Ideas on how to implement a design in next js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui, tailwind-css

I am working on frontend project in Next.js and Tailwind. I have a been given a Figma design to implement. There is this part where I am supposed to show some steps:

[image: Steps]

Any ideas of how I can implement the steps shown in the screenshot?

Comment: What specifically are you having issues with?

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question is too broad. You're expected to make an attempt and show your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider using slightly overlapping elements with `clip-path` to make the arrow shape:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="flex">
  <div class="bg-orange-200 p-4 grow [clip-path:polygon(0_0,calc(100%-1rem)_0,100%_50%,calc(100%-1rem)_100%,0_100%)]">
    Step 1
  </div>
  <div class="bg-stone-200 p-4 pl-8 grow -ml-2 [clip-path:polygon(0_0,calc(100%-1rem)_0,100%_50%,calc(100%-1rem)_100%,0_100%,1rem_50%)]">
    Step 2
  </div>
  <div class="bg-stone-200 p-4 pl-8 grow -ml-2 [clip-path:polygon(0_0,calc(100%-1rem)_0,100%_50%,calc(100%-1rem)_100%,0_100%,1rem_50%)]">
    Step 3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much , I have implemented your solution and it worked.